# JavaScript: Access object field that has dot as key

Tags: javascript

First I want to create some dynamic properties in JavaScript object.
Consider I have this code:

```js
a ="field"
o = {}
o[a]="some field"
console.log(o)
```

o object will have field property with value "some field", but when I need to add property that has object as value I do this:

```js
a ="field.foo"
o = {}
o[a]="child of field"
console.log(o)
```

than you can see that o have field.foo but when I access o.field.foo it returning undefined. What I want in the end is something like this:

```
{
   field :{foo:'child of field'}
}
```

but what I get is:

```
{
   field.foo:'child of field'
}
```

how to do that?

Comment: Using lodash: `_.set(o, a, 'child of field')`

Comment: You are not getting `field.foo` (an object called `field` with property of  `.foo`) you are getting a string `"field.foo"` as in `"field.foo":'child of field'` run your second example and look closely

Comment: is there any native way? @Paulpro

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto No, just the ways in the linked question.

Comment: Many thanks @Cœur. I will make sure I do additional edits as well as the issue I spot.